# Codeigniter 2 active record — How do I create temporary table to apply second sort order?

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I am in the middle of updating an old site. One of the things I am doing is rewriting the database queries because I have changed the structure of the database to make it more flexible and configurable from the admin.

I previously used the following query (and many others like it), which rely on a temporary table:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Links WHERE Cat LIKE ('$c') AND Type LIKE ('%$x%') LIMIT $s, $l) AS T ORDER BY $sort $o");
```

Because the queries have got more complicated and now involve a lot of joins I have decided to use active record syntax to make them easier to read. The problem is I cannot find any info on how to make a temporary table to apply a second sort to the data using active record; surely this is possible?

Here is my new query:

```
    $this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->from('item_categories')
        ->where('item_categories.cat_id', $c)
        ->or_where('item_categories.parent_id', $c)
        ->or_where('item_categories.gparent_id', $c)
        ->join('item_categories_rel', 'item_categories_rel.cat_id = item_categories.cat_id', 'right')
        ->join('item_entries', 'item_entries.item_id = item_categories_rel.item_id','right')
        ->join('ratings_total', 'ratings_total.item_id = item_entries.item_id')
        ->order_by("item_name", "asc")
        ->limit($l, $s);
        // up to here I want to store as a temporary table then apply next order
        //->order_by($sort, $o); - ideally I want to apply a second order like this
    $result = $this->db->get();
```

I would like to apply 'order by' twice but this doesn't work — active record is not that cleaver (or more likeley would be ambiguous), how can I can I do this this within active record?

Any help is much appreciated. Failing the active record approach can anyone suggest how I might apply a sort to the result object?

Answer (score 0):

Try check the generated SQL: `print $this->db->_compile_select()`. And a plus information: CI doesn't support subqueries.

Comment: I cant get this to work, I have tried running this function and it just gives me white screen of death - I think it's protected in latest ci https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries/issues/2 however I have looked at mysql log and it seems to be running as two separate queries - strange thing is the second one is being ignored by ci entirely - the results of the first are being returned. Is there any way I can achieve what I am trying to do in ci?

Comment: Sorry, please try `$this->db->last_query()` :) I hope it works.

Comment: Thank for the info uzolt, I have abandoned this approach, in favour of using javascript (jquery.tablesorter) to apply the second sort - this has made the site faster and allowed me to remove 9 sql queries replace them with one. I am still curios how I would do the above if I needed to though. When I have a chance I will look into this again.

Comment: I think it should work. But now I don't use CI's AR, I wrote a small library, because of AR's bugs.

I think it would be useful to write the sql query. If it's OK, your code has some errors. If the sql query isn't OK, check your desired query :)

Comment: The code did work, only problem was the second order query - I have commented this out for clarity. I can write the code as a direct sql query and create a temporary table and it works fine but no way to do that in active record

Comment: Oh. Save the raw sql (with `last_query()`) and combine with other query! You can "simulate" subqueries this way :)