# Codeigniter - How can I sort my database result object (sorting php objects)

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, object

Apparently active record cannot deal with temporary tables - huge oversight in my opinion. (ref: [Codeigniter 2 active record — How do I create temporary table to apply second sort order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518069/codeigniter-2-active-record-how-do-i-create-temporary-table-to-apply-second-so) )

In light of this I am looking for a way to sort the result object produced by my query.

Here is my query:

```
    $this->db
                ->select('*')
                ->from('item_categories')
                ->where('item_categories.cat_id', $c)
                ->or_where('item_categories.parent_id', $c)
                ->or_where('item_categories.gparent_id', $c)
                ->join('item_categories_rel', 'item_categories_rel.cat_id = item_categories.cat_id', 'right')
                ->join('item_entries', 'item_entries.item_id = item_categories_rel.item_id','right')
                ->join('ratings_total', 'ratings_total.item_id = item_entries.item_id')
                ->order_by("item_name", "asc")
                ->limit($l, $s);
            $result = $this->db->get();
```

So for example my results contain a field called site_rating which is of type decimal(2,1) , how can I sort my result object by site_rating in asc/desc order? Any help greatly appreciated.

To be clear I do not want to change the current order, I want to apply a second sort order to the first result set - I have found I cannot do this with active record so would like to do it by sorting the result object if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->db
                ->select('*')
                ->from('item_categories')
                ->where('item_categories.cat_id', $c)
                ->or_where('item_categories.parent_id', $c)
                ->or_where('item_categories.gparent_id', $c)
                ->join('item_categories_rel', 'item_categories_rel.cat_id = item_categories.cat_id', 'right')
                ->join('item_entries', 'item_entries.item_id = item_categories_rel.item_id','right')
                ->join('ratings_total', 'ratings_total.item_id = item_entries.item_id')
                ->order_by("site_rating", "DESC")
                ->limit($l, $s);
            $result = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: sorry I may not have been clear in my question. I need them sorted as they are, I then need to apply a second sort. So for example my original query gets the first 50 results by item name, I then want to sort those results by their rating

Comment: Can you make an example database on sql fiddle with a couple of items, then we can play with your database to give you the right result.